# Not able to import getpass in python

Tags: python, weblogic, importerror, wlst

I have a requirement to input username and password from the console. For the password I am using

```
password = getpass.getpass('Enter password')
```

I have used `import getpass` But getting

```
ImportError : no module named getpass
```

Also tried setting the pythonpath using

```
export pythonpath=/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages:/usr/lib/python2.4
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4

import sys
import getpass

WL_USER = raw_input('Enter the username to login to BI EM:')
WL_PASSWD = getpass.getpass('Enter the password:')
HOST_NAME = raw_input('Enter the BI host URL')
WL_PORT = raw_input('Enter the admin port for BI')
```

error:

```
ImportError: no module named getpass
```

One important thing is that I am trying to run the script as a wlst script i.e. trying to edit the attribute of an Mbean. So the execution goes like this:
    /home/wlserver_10.3/common/bin/wlst.sh test.py

I tried to execute the script as python test.py
It executes fine. So it looks like there is some issue with wlst. 
Need assistance on this.

Comment: Is there `/usr/lib/python2.4/getpass.py` in you system?

Comment: No /usr/lib/python2.4 has only site-packages as a subfolder

Comment: Sounds like your installation of Python is broken -- reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `getpass.getpass()` was added in python 2.5.  Check the old manual, http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/module-getpass.html

Comment: Ok i edited that but the problem is that it is not able to import getpass

Answer (score 0):

A bit old but Your file is probably named "getpass.py"